# LAN/offline alternatives to PubNub?

Tags: javascript, python, raspberry-pi, lan, pubnub

I made my last project in pubnub and now I need make it work on separated LAN. I have a raspberry like server with python scripts which communicate with javascript on web.

I know that pubnub is cloud service, so my question is what is the best solution to make it work? 
Is there anything like pubnub what works without internet connection?

Comment: We have many home automation customers that use bluetooth or the like when the remote control is on the same network. This does not use PubNub but allows for off internet communication.

Comment: I have only wifi, no bluetooth (Pi zero). I was searching for some solution last days, but it looks like I should rebuild whole program to using websocket. I was thinking if there is any LAN solution like pubnub which sending messages between python and javascript, thats why I asked here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: For local wifi, you could rely on redis, perhaps but for internet scale (when the device is online), it will be difficult to scale and very expensive this to many thousands or more if you do this yourself.

Comment: Thanks, redis looks like a good solution for local wifi.